# Should I unsubscribe from all my controllers events while not needed?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have Winforms application. My application take Pcap files and transmit all the packets from this files through the machine adapter.

In my UI I have many controllers events for example all my `GridView` event `(CellChanged, RowChanged...)`

While my application is in the middle of the transmit I don't need that, all my `UI` update is via timer that check my class that responsible for this transmit so my question is should I unsubscribe from all this events?

There is a benefit to do that?

Comment: No, that's not normally necessary or advantageous.

Comment: If anything It will probably slow down your app

Comment: unsubscribe from all this events will slow down my app ??

Comment: The unsubscribe takes time, subscribing again takes time, and its very error prone. unless you are goning to close everything, throw it away, and recreate it later. And having stuff subscribed to events, in itself, doesnt cost anything.

Comment: But how it takes time ? after click on my play button, before the play operation i am unsubscribe and immediately start the play, i didn't see any freeze or something.

Comment: @AK_ - Can you expand upon why unsubscribing from events is slow and error prone? An example and/or citation would be helpful.

Comment: More than anything else - Its pointless. I need to see the code to really tell but I'm almost certain unsubscribing events won't give you any benefit what so ever. It isn't especially slow or more error prone than most tedious programming tasks, but since you probably won't gain anything...

Answer (score 0):

You can unsubscribe from some events, if this events did his job and in the future do not need to perform these events. Also unsubscribe from events if you do not need to perform it while executing some operation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unsubscribe events. Since your UI updates via timer just use your desired events on the timer. Unsubscribing will not give you that much advantage

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: Seems that my answer was to short, adding few more options for you:

- You will not use the controllers anymore: **UNREGISTER** - objects will stay in memory until any reference exists to them. So you will minimize memory leaks.
- You will use controllers with another UI: **UNREGISTER** - memory leaks will be on side of UI objects.
- You will use both UI and controllers again: You can unregister and register them again, or just add a bool that these handlers should be disabled for a period of time.

If the handlers do some extensive code you can also see performance improvements when you stop executing them when not needed.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but a couple of comments, especially now that you're saying that you think you got down-voted because your answer was too short. The problem with your answer is that you're wrong. First, regarding the possibility of memory leaks, there is nothing in the OP's question that would indicate that his program is large and complicated and prone to memory leak problems, or that UI event handler subscription could cause memory leaks.

Comment: Second, the OP described what the event handlers are used for - they are apparently involved in formatting grid data, and they are not likely to be doing "extensive code", especially when the UI is not being used. So the idea of getting "performance improvements" by unsubscribing them is very, very unlikely - and if it was true it would indicate a bug that should be properly fixed, not just worked around by unsubscribing and subscribing the buggy event handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. We can guess that the application is very small in size, so leaks are not a major issue. I have started to think of them myself, when my apps grows, users kept it opened for 14days and started to recieve OutOfMem exceptions. If he starts to think of them earlier only better for him.

Comment: EventHandlers - they don't see formating to me, but input ones. So from my point of view I can imagine start of file transmit when file path is entered into grid, which can have serious problems with concurrency etc. But not necessary.